# Ignore CDATA tags for syntax highlighting in Sublime Text 3

Tags: opencart, sublimetext3, sublimetext, cdata, vqmod

I frequently use Sublime Text for editing vQmod code.  For those that don't know, vQmod is a dynamic search/replace application that uses XML to modify the core files in OpenCart dynamically.  Both the search position and the code to be added are typically contained within `CDATA` tags.  Understandably, all syntax highlighting rules regard anything within `CDATA` tags as a block of plain text with no language rules applied.  But in this case, the code contained therein can be HTML, PHP, JavaScript or inline CSS.

Is there a way I can modify the syntax highlighting rules so that text contained within the CDATA tags will still be evaluated as code?

Here is an example:

```xml
<operation>
    <search position="after"><![CDATA[public function index()]]></search>
    <add><![CDATA[
        $data['examples'] = $this->model_extension_extension->getExamples();
    ]]>
    </add>
</operation>
```

The `<search>` code is less important, but I would whatever lies within `<add><![CDATA[` and `]]></add>` to be recognized as php.  Sometimes these are extremely long blocks code and having the proper syntax highlighting here would really help.

Answer (score 5):

I encountered this issue as well as the entire CDATA section is my HTML. My workaround is to open the document with syntax type SCALA. RUBY works as well, but I think SCALA is highlighting is more relevant.

Comment: thanks that's a bit better than one flat color.  it's still wrong highlighting in many ways but it's a decent workaround.